# jQuery skdslider Slider not loading sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, slider

Facing issue with [skdslider](http://dandywebsolution.com/skdslider/)

It is not loading sometimes when I refresh (CTRL + R) the page.

URL - http://goo.gl/yZgtSr

Studied doc, tried shifting HTML / CSS / JS files, slider ids / classes but didn't work.

I could see in console, slider is working but the `id="demo1"` don't get height sometimes.

```
<div id="demo1" class="skdslider" style="height: 677px;">
```